# Simplify the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{90}{n}p^n(1-p)^{90-n}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Can I simplify this sum $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{90}{n}p^n(1-p)^{90-n}$$

Comment: Yes you can. Search for Vandermonde's formula

Comment: You didn't show too much of working there! But as suggested above, using the Vandermonde's identity: $\binom{m}{k}.\binom{n}{r-k} = \binom{m+n}{r}$.

Comment: Try using the Binomial Theorem.  Vandermonde would help to answer the original question: $$\large\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{30}{k}\binom{60}{n-k}$$ which may have been changed to hide the fact that that question had been asked here.